# Use result of query to get values from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in this format:

TABLE1: *id | name | info*

and

TABLE2: *name | moreinfo*

I have a query which returns a list of *name*'s from the first table. I then want to use those to get the respective *moreinfo* from the other table. For example, if the names a, b were returned and and in TABLE 2 I had *a | apple, b | bread* I would want apple and bread returned.

Any thoughts on the best way to go about doing this? Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hint : `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just want a join here:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.moreinfo
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

If you wanted to report all names in the first table, even if they had no matching names in the second table, you could use a left join instead:

```
SELECT t1.name, COALESCE(t2.moreinfo, 'NA') AS moreinfo
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally you seem to ask for the Apple and Bread to be returned but not neccessarily other information associated with the name.  It is unclear how the query results you have are formatted.

```
select moreinfo from table2 where name in (YOURQUERYRESULT);
```

YOURQUERYRESULT can be a query returning only the name or a list with the names.

The question is answered elsewhere with join examples where you might want to substitute table with the query you have.

```
select a.id, a.name, a.info, b.moreinfo 
from (YOURQUERY) a 
join table2 b on a.name=b.name
```

I suggest you add an id column in table2 to identify the user and join on that field.  Names change and multiple users have the same name.

Best regards,
Bjarni